# Data version-control in TFS/Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, version-control

I have a requirement to version the lookup/configuration tables in my project. We make use of multiple development-databases and often switch between them which causes lots of problems as reference-tables are not always same in all databases. So, a developer often forgets the data with which he coded a defect. Is there any TFS or SSDT tool available that does data version-control? Else, can you share some ideas how version-control in this scenario should be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the script to populate your lookup data and then add to source control?

If you are using SSDT you can add a post build script that will call out to other sql scripts. you can add your Lookup table population scripts here, and then they would run each time you deployed the database

Comment: I was looking for some automation that we can use to check-in static data changes every time we do it. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

RedGate has a [tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) that might meet your needs.  I haven't used it personally, but their website says "Source control your schemas and reference data" and "Store and share any SQL Server object and static data".

Comment: I am not sure if we can afford a new tool now.. but thanks for the direction.